# Importing bootstrap.less file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

I have a simple folder system:

```
   |_ JS
   |  |_ bootstrap.min
   |_ SOURCE
   |  |_ BOOTSTRAP
   |  |  |_ *.less (all bootstrap 3.3.4 .less files copied form the bootstrap less folder
   |  |_ style.less
   |_ index.html
```

where the 'style.less' file looks as follows:

```
// Bootstrap LESS
@import 'bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
```

and I have a simple index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="source/style.less" type="text/less">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.0/less.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                text 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                text 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

in this compilation it doesn't work :(

but if I change the href source from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="source/style.less" type="text/less">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="source/bootstrap/bootstrap.less" type="text/less">
```

all the code works fine... what is wrong? I have no idea... please help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the style.less file to

```
@import './bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
```

It may work, otherwise you can have both files in the html. One is the standard bootstrap and the other containing your custom styles.

Comment: i solved the problem by retyping it step by step one more time... thx for Your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

as explained on this link : http://lesscss.org/ ;

download less.js and include it in a  tag in the  element of your page: